# Setting a global variable in a thread - C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, thread-safety

I have an HTTP server that I am writing using HTTP listener, and I would like to somehow declare certain variables as accessible from anywhere within a thread.

- My webserver class is instanced based, so I can't really use a static variable.
- I could use an instance variable as all of the code is in one class, but...I don't know.

I thought of using a dictionary: `Dictionary</*[type of Thread ID here]*/,ThreadData>`, but I'm concerned there might be threading issues. `ThreadData` would *probably* be a class instance, but I might use a struct, depending on which would be more efficient.

- If I would key the dictionary to the Thread IDs and program it so that one thread would *only* ask for its own entry in the dictionary, would there be any thread-related problems when accessing the dictionary?
- Each thread would add its own entry. Would I have to lock the dictionary while I add new thread items? If so, would I be able to use a separate lock object to allow threads to access their own data in the meantime?

Would there be an advantage to using a concurrent dictionary? Is there another way that is more thread-safe?

I am currently using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. I don't know for sure that this uses a new thread for each item. If not then I could also key it to the context.

**Update:** According to [ThreadPool class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it does reuse threads. And it does not clear thread data.

> When the thread pool reuses a thread, it does not clear the data in thread local storage or in fields that are marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute. Therefore, when a method examines thread local storage or fields that are marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute, the values it finds might be left over from an earlier use of the thread pool thread.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class?

Comment: Because you have a distinct entry point for your worker threads and you write the worker logic yourself, it shouldn't be a problem for you to wipe the old thread data.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One solution would be to use a **public static field**, with the [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[ThreadStatic]
public static int ThreadSpecificStaticValue;
```

> A static field marked with ThreadStaticAttribute is not shared between
>   threads. Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field,
>   and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is
>   accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value.

Comment: Neat. Didn't know that one.

Comment: So what is the difference between this method, and Gene's answer? They both apparently accomplish the same thing. I guess Gene's method could be accessed from anywhere in the Thread, whereas this one follows standard access conventions. This one is easier. +1 to both of you :)

Comment: @ArlenBeiler This link should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh.aspx

Comment: @ArlenBeiler - The ThreadStatic is not only easier, it's also better performance wise.

Comment: ThreadLocal<T> may be even better than [ThreadStatic] in that the variable can be initialized for every thread; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333885/threadstatic-v-s-threadlocalt-is-generic-better-than-attribute

Answer (score 7):

You could use the built in storage mechanism of the thread class:

```
public class Program
{
  private static LocalDataStoreSlot _Slot = Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("webserver.data");

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var threads = new List<Thread>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      var thread = new Thread(DoWork);
      threads.Add(thread);
      thread.Start(i);
    }

    foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Join();
  }

  private static void DoWork(object data)
  {
    // initially set the context of the thread
    Thread.SetData(_Slot, data);

    // somewhere else, access the context again
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ID {0}: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.GetData(_Slot));
  }

}
```

Sample output:

[image]

That'll work with threads spawned by the thread pool as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver is instance based, why not keep all of the required data in there? If each instance is locked to a certain thread, there should be no problem.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler How many cores does your machine have? Threading every request would be pretty suboptimal. It would be better to write a request scheduler that will distribute work over some number of threads.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to create a HTTP Server , Use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) , looks weirdo answer but think about it